# How does XOR really works, and what is the magic behind it?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary, bitwise-operators

The question is maybe misleading a little bit but I didn't know how to ask it another way. 
There is a problem in hackerrank that goes as follow:

> Consider an array of  integers, where all but one of the integers
>   occur in pairs. In other words, every element in  occurs exactly twice
>   except for one unique element.
>
> Given the array find and print the unique element. [2,3,1,3,2] -> result is 1

[image]

I solved the problem like this:

```
private static int lonelyInteger(int[] a) {
        if(a==null)
            return 0;

         if(a.length<2)
             return a.length;

        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

        for(int i : a){

            if(set.contains(i)){
                set.remove(i);
            }else{
                set.add(i);
            }            
        }

        return (Integer) set.toArray()[0];
    }
```

However it turned our that there is a neat solution to this problem which is:

```
private static int lonelyInteger(int[] a) {
         int b = a[0];

         for(int i = 1; i < a.length; i++){
             b ^= a[i];
         }
        return b;       
    }
```

The problem is that is I don't know WHY IT WORKS ?! 
I understand HOW it works but don't understand WHY IT WORKS ? 
To understand that I made a small program to output the results of each step:

```
public class BitwiseOperator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int[] a = new int[n];
        int sum = 0;
        in.nextLine();
        String line = in.nextLine();
        String[] numbers = line.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            a[i] = Integer.valueOf(numbers[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            binary(sum, a[i]);
            sum ^= a[i];
            binary(sum);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();

        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }


    private static void binary(int sum) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%16s", Integer.toBinaryString(sum)).replace(' ', '0') + " ->" + sum);
    }

    private static void binary(int sum, int i) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%16s", Integer.toBinaryString(sum)).replace(' ', '0') + " ->" + sum);
        System.out.println("XOR");
        System.out.println(String.format("%16s", Integer.toBinaryString(i)).replace(' ', '0') + " ->" + i);
        System.out.println("--------");
    }


}
```

If you enter the following input:

5

2 3 2 1 3

The output is:

```
0000000000000000 ->0
XOR
0000000000000010 ->2
--------
0000000000000010 ->2



0000000000000010 ->2
XOR
0000000000000011 ->3
--------
0000000000000001 ->1



0000000000000001 ->1
XOR
0000000000000010 ->2
--------
0000000000000011 ->3



0000000000000011 ->3
XOR
0000000000000001 ->1
--------
0000000000000010 ->2



0000000000000010 ->2
XOR
0000000000000011 ->3
--------
0000000000000001 ->1



1
```

So the program actually works BUT I Really need to understand WHY ?

Comment: `A xor A == 0` that's why duplicates cancel out; if we have all but one items being duplicates then xoring the items will return the item that is distinct

Comment: @DmitryBychenko your comment should be an answer, because it's neat, short, comprehensive and correct.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Yes I understand that but what happens when it is A XOR B XOR C XOR A XOR B why it is 0 too ?

Comment: @Adelin Because the order in which you XOR things doesn't matter because XOR is just addition without carrying. And `(0 XOR A) = A`, so `A XOR B XOR C XOR A XOR B` = `(B XOR B) XOR (C XOR X) XOR A` = `0 XOR 0 XOR A` = `0 XOR A` = `A`. All the ones that appear twice cancel to zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An accurate proof, IMHO, involves *group theory* (you can build *abelian group* based on `xor`):

1. `xor` is a group operation
2. `0` is a group `0`
3. `A` is an inverse element (so any `A` is inverse one to itself).

Of course we have to prove that `(A xor B) xor C == A xor (B xor C)`

Since `A xor B == B xor A` we have an *abelian group* and that's why can regroup 
items in any order:

```
  A XOR B XOR C XOR A XOR B ==
 (A XOR A) XOR (B XOR B) XOR C ==
  C
```

In general case:

```
   A xor B xor ... xor Z ==
  (A xor A) xor (B xor B) xor ... xor (distinct Item) ==
   0 xor 0 xor ... xor (distinct Item) ==
   distinct Item
```

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Exactly what I was looking for, now I will go and read about abelian group to wipe the rust out of my math skills :D

Answer (score 1):

Consider an array of integers, where all but one of the integers occur in pairs. In other words, every element in it occurs exactly twice except for one unique element. Now imagine you add all those numbers.

What does it mean if that sum is even? It means that the number that appears once must be even. What does it mean if that sum is odd? It means that the number that appears once must be odd. Think about this until you understand it.

Now imagine that instead of summing them, we just kept track if the sum was even or odd. So if the first two numbers were 3 and 7, the sum would be 10, but we'd just remember that it was even. This would still work. The final answer would be even if the number that appears once is even and odd if the number that appears once is odd. Think about this until you understand it.

So that's how we could make it work for one bit of the numbers. But we could also do that for all the bits at the same time, tracking for each bit position whether the total was odd or even. When done, we'd have whether the number that appeared once was odd or even for each bit position, and that's all we need. Since we're doing it in binary, the only odd number for that position is 1 and the only even one is 0. Think about this until you understand it.

Comment: Sorry, I have forget to mean the restrictions, I have edited the question and added the restrictions, please edit your answer accordingly :)

Comment: @Adelin No need. The answer is still perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to keep it short and simple.

**XOR to the same number returns 0**.

Example:
23 ^ 23 = 0
-325 ^ -325 = 0

*So while you run through the loop the XOR of, numbers appearing twice will cancel out itself and finally you will get the number which is unique.*